# Raster projection changes to none when loading into MapWindows after already being defined in ArcMap

Tags: coordinate-system, mapwindow

I am trying to load a number of raster files (.tif) into MapWindows v.4.8.8. These rasters have previously been reprojected in ArcMap to have the projection WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_60S and saved with this projection. When I load these rasters into MapWindows their projection comes up as "none" and I can't run any analysis on them as a "no spatial reference information" error pops up. I am very new to using MapWindows but I need to use it for a specific plug-in.

[image]